# Atoms do not have colour, but objects which are nothing but the assembly of atoms have colour! How is that possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

Objects are made up of atoms, and objects have colour, but atoms, as my understanding goes, do not have colour, so how is it possible that colourless atoms form objects which have colour?